# How to calculate the area of a polygon in real meter in OpenLayers?

Tags: postgis, openlayers, area

I'm trying to figured out why I'm getting weird results from ol/sphere/getArea.

I draw an rectangle with fixed size of 5x5 meter. To translate 5 meters to map units, I do the following:

```
const factor = getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, cursorCoordinate);
const forceHeight = 5 / factor;
const forceWidth = 5 / factor;
```

Now I show the measurements in real meters.

For each side of the polygon, I calculate the length like this:

```
const factor = getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, lineGeometry.getCoordinates()[0]);
const lengthInMeter = lineGeometry.getLength() * factor;
```

Which give me 5.00 meter for each side.

But if I call ol/sphere/getArea(polygonGeometry) for the same feature, I get 24.94.

I have this geometry in my Postgres DB with the PostGIS extension.

If I call

> st_area(geometry, true)

for this geometry, I get 25.04

If I call

> st_area(geometry, false)

I get 24.94, so the same value I get from ol/sphere/getArea.

```
(select st_area(ST_Transform((geometry), 4326)::geography, true) from object_table where id = 1)
```

The documentation for the second parameter says: "To compute the area using the faster but less accurate spherical model use ST_Area(geog, false)."
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html

So OpenLayers do the less accurate calculation all the time?

How I'm able to get 25 m^2 for a 5x5 rectangle, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the wrong CRS. EPSG 3857 is notoriously uncertain when it comes to distance and area calculation. Transform your data to a fitting local CRS, probably a UTM-strip, then redo the calculation.

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Comment: As the import path `ol/sphere/getArea` suggests OpenLayers uses spherical geometry (assumes the Earth is a sphere) and not the more complex Vincenty calculation for an ellipsoid.  Both are more suitable for long distance calculations on a curved surface, not for accuracies of less than a meter.  For short distance of a few meters the projections units area divided by factor squared would be just as accurate.

Comment: Thank you all. @Mike this is my solution now, I get 25 ^^ const areaInSquareMeter = polygon.getArea() * Math.pow(factor, 2);

Comment: @Mike This kind of questions appear a lot. I think it would be good if you put your comment into answer.